# How can I reduce array with non-unique elements by summing their second value with lodash/underscore?

Tags: arrays, underscore.js, lodash

How to get from this array

```
[
    {name: "a", weight: 1}, 
    {name: "b", weight: 3}, 
    {name: "a", weight: 5},
    {name: "b", weight: 7}
]
```

get this array(weight of duplicates summed)

```
[
    {name: "a", weight: 6}, 
    {name: "b", weight: 10}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work using `groupBy` `reduce` and `pluck`:

```
var sum = function(a,b){ return a+b; };

_.chain([
    {name: "a", weight: 1}, 
    {name: "b", weight: 3}, 
    {name: "a", weight: 5},
    {name: "b", weight: 7}
]).groupBy('name') // we first group them by name
.map(function(v){  // them we map group to the name, and the sum of weights
      return {name:v[0].name,weight:_.pluck(v,"weight").reduce(sum)};
}).value(); // finally, we get the value
```

Note that we are `reduce`ing using native JavaScript reduce, if you want Underscore's reduce you need to chain inside before the `_.pluck`, call `.reduce` and then call `.value`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any fancy Underscore stuff for this, you can do it all with a single [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) call:

```
var result = a.reduce(function(m, e) {
    if(!m.by_name[e.name]) {
        m.by_name[e.name] = { name: e.name, weight: 0 };
        m.a.push(m.by_name[e.name]);
    }
    m.by_name[e.name].weight += e.weight;
    return m;
}, { a: [ ], by_name: { } });
```

Then your array will be in `result.a`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/6UaXr/

If you must, you can use `_.reduce` instead of the native `reduce`.

There are a couple tricks here:

1. The `reduce` memo caches the results by name in an object and in an array at the same time. Indexing by in `m.by_name` gives you quick lookups but you want an array as the final result so we build that along the way too.
2. The by-name object and the array share the same references so incrementing through `m.by_name[e.name]` also updates the array.
3. The `by_name` entries are created (and the references carefully shared) the first time we need them. We also initialize the cached weights with zero so that all the summarizing is done in a single `m.by_name[e.name].weight += e.weight`.